# Update to Xcode 5.1.1 changed my table view behaviour

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview

I was working in Xcode 4.6 and have a basic `UItableview` set up where the cells are populated from an array. When working in 4.6, the view behaved perfectly and was just how I liked it. After the update to 5.1.1, scrolling seems to have been enabled on the table view, the table view is loaded from the bottom of the view and the 3 populated cells at the top are not visible. Sometimes the view will rubber band and not allow me to scroll all the way back up to the top, and sometimes it won't rubber band and will let me. I am fairly new to this, but have tried messing around with auto layout, but to no avail.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


_Manufacturers = @[@"1",
                   @"2",
                   @"3"];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return _Manufacturers.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath       *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";
TableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...

int row = [indexPath row];

cell.TitleLabel.text = _Manufacturers[row];


return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for UITableView working in Xcode 4.6 should work perfectly in Xcode 5.1.1. Major change I have observed is that table moves under status bar. This can be fixed-up by below snippet :

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars=NO;
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;
```

However, **provide code** so that I can get what's going on.

Comment: The suggestion there unfortunately didn't work. What code would you like to see? The .m file?

Comment: @user3580512 Try using _Manufacturers as an NSArray / NSMutableArray instead of String array. This should fix out issue!

Comment: _Manufactures is already defined as an NSArray is the .h file. Anything else I need to do with that?